# Finding the closer player with NavMesh

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop, path-finding

In my scene, I have my NavMesh in the center (the yellow one) with 3 cubes set to be tracked. I want the NavMesh to find the closest one with the shortest path to it out of all the cubes and start following it. I have written code to do so, yet it acts weird and I don't see anything wrong with it, but obviously something is. What's happening is when I click play and leave the cubes as is, the NavMesh does, in fact, find the path to the closest cube and start heading towards it (cube3), but when it almost gets to it, the NavMesh takes a hard turn and starts heading towards cube 1 which is obviously not the closer one.

[image]

Here is my code. PathLength works just fine. I think the problem lies within the CalcPath function.

```
float PathLength(Vector3 target){
    NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath ();
    myNavMesh.CalculatePath (target, path);
    int i = 1;
    float currentPathLength = 0;
    Vector3 lastCorner;
    Vector3 currentCorner;
    lastCorner = path.corners [0];

    while (i < path.corners.Length) {
        currentCorner = path.corners [i];
        currentPathLength += Vector3.Distance (lastCorner, currentCorner);
        Debug.DrawLine (lastCorner, currentCorner, Color.red,1f);
        lastCorner = currentCorner;
        i++;
    }

    return currentPathLength;
}


void CalcPath(){
    Vector3 closestTarget = Vector3.zero;
    float lastPathLength = Mathf.Infinity;
    float currentPathLength = 0;

    foreach (GameObject player in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")) {

        currentPathLength = PathLength (player.transform.position);

        if (currentPathLength < lastPathLength) {
            closestTarget = player.transform.position;
        }

        lastPathLength = currentPathLength;
    }

    myNavMesh.SetDestination (closestTarget);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have an issue in `CalcPath`.  I'll try to give an example to show you what's wrong.  Say the distances to the players are as follows: `[5,20,10]`.  Obviously Player A is closest, but `CalcPath` will return Player C.  I'll go through your loop to show why:

**First Iteration:**
`currentPathLength : 0 -> 5`
`closestTarget : null -> PlayerA.transform.position`
`lastPathLength : Mathf.Infinity -> 5`

**Second Iteration:**
`currentPathLength : 5 -> 20`
`closestTarget : PlayerA.transform.position -> PlayerA.transform.position` *(unchanged)*
`lastPathLength : 5 -> 20`

**Third Iteration**:  *(this is where your problem lies)*
`currentPathLength : 20 -> 10` *(this is* ***less*** *than `lastPathLength`)*
`closestTarget : PlayerA.transform.position -> PlayerC.transform.position`
`lastPathLength : 20 -> 10`

To fix this issue, instead of storing `lastPathLength`, store a minimum path length and only change your `closestTarget` when you have a new minimum.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The lastPathLength is useless in my case. I figured this out and posted my answer, but I will keep my answer down on here and accept yours since it explains what is happening. Maybe it will help someone. Thanks :-D

Answer (score 0):

I was comparing the current path length to the last path length and not storing the shortest path and comparing it. I set a new variable called "closestTargetLength" and compared that to the current path length, and works perfect.

```
float PathLength(Vector3 target){
    NavMeshPath path = new NavMeshPath ();
    myNav.CalculatePath (target, path);
    int i = 1;
    float currentPathLength = 0;
    Vector3 lastCorner;
    Vector3 currentCorner;

    lastCorner = path.corners [0];
    while (i < path.corners.Length) {
        currentCorner = path.corners [i];
        currentPathLength += Vector3.Distance (lastCorner, currentCorner);
        Debug.DrawLine (lastCorner, currentCorner, Color.red);
        lastCorner = currentCorner;
        i++;
    }

    return currentPathLength;
}


void CalcPath(){
    Vector3 closestTarget = Vector3.zero;
    float closestTargetLength = Mathf.Infinity;
    float lastPathLength = Mathf.Infinity;
    float currentPathLength = 0;

    foreach (GameObject player in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player")) {

        currentPathLength = PathLength (player.transform.position);

        if (currentPathLength < closestTargetLength) {
            closestTarget = player.transform.position;
            closestTargetLength = currentPathLength;
        }
        lastPathLength = currentPathLength;
    }

    myNav.SetDestination (closestTarget);
}
```